# NLP Code Mixed : Code Switching

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp, stanford-nlp, opennlp

I am engaged in a competition where we have to build a system using given data set. I am trying to learn the proceedings in linguistics research.

The main goal of this task is to identify the sentence level sentiment polarity of the code-mixed dataset of Indian languages pairs. Each of the sentences is annotated with language information as well as polarity at the sentence level.

Anyone interested to participate with me??

If anyone can help me over it. It will be great.

Please reach me out soon as possible.

Comment: Is this bootstrap related?

Comment: do you want to change navbar background color ?? or only the text color ??

Comment: `.navbar {   background-color:blue; }` will change the background color but then the contrast would be to small: [check the codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JRpwLP)
What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: [ https://fiddle.jshell.net/tjbaezid/eLwoxo26/1/ ] background-color, border-color, hover effect set blue and all text white. You can use this and also custom hover focus effect. for help regarding this ask me anytime. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try change navbar-inverse element.
Example:

```
.navbar-inverse { background-color: #fff;   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think easy solution is remove navbar-inverse class and place this css.

`.navbar {
    background-color: blue;
}`

Answer (score 0):

as suggested by others you can use

```
.navbar-inverse {
    background-color: #3F51B5;
    border-color: #233598;
}
```

additionally you can use more styling see my fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/15317/)